# Strange Behaviour: SQL And operator with multiple IN operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using multiple IN operators with AND in my sql query where clause as given below...

```
---
where ID in (1, 3, 234, 2332, 2123, 989) AND tag in ('wow', 'wonderful')
```

But surprisingly behaviour of result seems to be of OR type rather then AND type. What I mean is it is ignoring AND operator...

Can you please explain me why?

Comment: what makes you say that? Did you get back a result row you didn't expect? What does that look like?

Comment: Are columns tag and id in one table or different? It's better to see whole query.

Comment: Thanks X2 and Mark_s it got resolved... your counter questions gave me hints which led it to get resolved... I was using joined table in query and incorrectly mapped ids... 

Thanks again

Comment: If you answered your own question, can you add an answer below that describes it and then accept it? Then the question won't show up as "Unanswered" anymore/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the result using SQL Server 2008.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM 
> (
>   SELECT 0 AS ID, 'wow' as Tag
> ) X
> WHERE ID in (1, 3, 234, 2332, 2123, 989) AND tag in ('wow', 'wonderful')
> ```

Result:
No records

> ```
> SELECT * FROM 
> (
>   SELECT 1 AS ID, 'wow' as Tag
> ) X
> WHERE ID in (1, 3, 234, 2332, 2123, 989) AND tag in ('wow', 'wonderful')
> ```

Result:

> ```
> ID    Tag
> 1  wow
> ```

Check your code again.